# RXTX Arduino USB with Windows

Tags: java, windows, arduino, rxtx

I have to connect the Arduino board I got with Java and get data from it. The board itself is working correctly (tested on another computer with a Oython script).

My problem now is to actually use the USB port. I correctly installed the RXTX library, and it does list the available port, but only COM ports and not USB ones.

```
while (enumComm.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
    System.out.println(currPortId.getName());
}
```

This is the code I'm using to iterate though the available ports. The output looks like:

```
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
COM3
COM4
```

I'm using Windows. For Linux there are lots of posts, and it seems to be so much easier there as they simple appear in the list without any additional help/changed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the USB port properly detected as a COM port? Look in the Device Manager, you should have something like this:

[image]